# ASP.NET List Box

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I am creating a web site in which one page has a list box in which set of names will be displayed.There s another box next to this box.User should be able to select few names from the first list,hit a arrow button,doing which all the selected names of first box will appear on the second box.
Can anyone please help me out as to how to do this??

Comment: How is your app structured? Webforms or MVC pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that id of the ">>" button is btnLoad and its click event handler is btnLoad_Click

lst1 is First List box and lst2 is Second list box:

```
    protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lst1.GetSelectedIndices();
        foreach (int item in lst1.GetSelectedIndices())
        {
            lst2.Items.Add(lst1.Items[item]);    
        }
    }
```

be sure that both list boxes should have

```
SelectionMode="Multiple"
```

or

```
         protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        lst1.GetSelectedIndices();
        foreach (int item in lst1.GetSelectedIndices())
        {
            var tempItem = lst1.Items[item];
            tempItem.Selected = false;
            lst2.Items.Add(tempItem);    
        }
     }
```

with

```
SelectionMode="Single"
```

hope it helps