# Select multiple value in DropDownList using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: asp.net

Select multiple value in DropDownList using ASP.NET and C#. I tried it to select single value from drop down but unable to find multiple selection.

Answer (score 42):

In that case you should use `ListBox` control instead of dropdown and Set the `SelectionMode` property to `Multiple`

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
  <asp:ListItem Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="test3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: can we get checkboxes to select multiple values

Comment: @downvoter.. Please let me the suitable reason for down vote and if there is better solution than this the please share that as well.

Comment: @Sachin How to make the listbox only shows the options on user click? The list box is showing all the options by default. can we  avoid this

Comment: You can refer this Link [Add and display CheckBoxList (CheckBoxes) in DropDownList](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-and-display-CheckBoxList-CheckBoxes-in-DropDownList-in-ASPNet.aspx) for dropdowncheckboxlist using bootstrap and multiselect.

Answer (score 26):

Take a look at the [ListBox](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_listbox.asp) control to allow multi-select.

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lblMultiSelect" SelectionMode="multiple">
            <asp:ListItem Text="opt1" Value="opt1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="opt2" Value="opt2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="opt3" Value="opt3" />
</asp:ListBox>
```

in the code behind

```
foreach(ListItem listItem in lblMultiSelect.Items)
    {
       if (listItem.Selected)
       {
          var val = listItem.Value;
          var txt = listItem.Text; 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Dropdown list wont allows multiple item select in dropdown.

If you need , you can use **listbox** control..

[ASP.NET List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721901/asp-net-list-box)

Answer (score 2):

For multiple selection dropdown list,cannot accomplish it directly using dropdown..Can be done in similar ways..

Either you have to use checkbox list or listbox (ajax inclusive)

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55184/MultiSelect-Dropdown-in-ASP-NET
>
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54374df7-5a54-42bc-83b8-ad5994cb634d/multi-select-dropdownlist
>
> http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1591-multiselect-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-using-csharp-40-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ListBox` control and `LINQ` you can try this:

**Code Example:**

```
control.Items.Cast< ListItem >().Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();
```

I hope this solves your issue!

Comment: if you need selectedvalues ... ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value)).ToList();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).