# I want to auto select 2 drop down lists items in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Here is the code of dropdown in actually from dropdown only item selected by default when we click on droppdown but I want 2 items to be selected from the dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dd1" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Female"  Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="yes" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="no" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="hello" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18824638/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select multiple value in DropDownList using ASP.NET and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824638/select-multiple-value-in-dropdownlist-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp)