# How to save all seletected items from dropdown list into my database table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a a dropdown list that stores multiple items but i tried multiple things and i am not able to store them at all.

So the porpuse of this is: A user have to fill a form and in there they will have a dropdown list where they can select the orders number they want.
I have tried to do a foreach but it didnt work. Some people told me to try with ajax but i sont really know how that works.
Resume:
I have to store the selected items and then insert them in my database table.

asp.net

```
 <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Encomenda"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="multiple" style="width: 150px"  runat="server" multiple></asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonCreate" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="ButtonCreate_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Select2 -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#DropDownListPorto").select2({
                /*placeholder: "Select a programming language",*/
                allowClear: true
            });
            $("#DropDownListPais").select2({
                /*placeholder: "Select a programming language",*/
                allowClear: true
            });
            $("#multiple").select2({
                /*placeholder: "Select a programming language",*/
                allowClear: true
            });
        </script>
```

C#

```
protected void ButtonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtBL.Enabled == true && txtBL.Text != "")
            {
                string email = "miguel.araujo@gatopreto.com";
                string email1 = "andre.vicente@gatopreto.com";
                string cc = "miguel.araujo@gatopreto.com";
                string BLbooking = txtBL.Text;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBL.Text))
                {
                    Erro.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (txtBL.Text.Length > 5)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Booking (BL, Data_booking) values (@BL, @date)", con);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BL", BLbooking);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("embarques@gatopreto.pt");
                            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("10.7.0.102");
                            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                            MailMessage msguser = new MailMessage();
                            msguser.Subject = "Novo Booking";
                            msguser.From = from;
                            msguser.CC.Add(cc);
                            msguser.Body = "Booking criado pela DSV. BL: " + BLbooking + " ";
                            msguser.IsBodyHtml = true;
                            msguser.To.Add(email);
                            msguser.To.Add(email1);
                            smtp.Send(msguser);
                            BookingSent.Visible = true;
                            txtBL.Text = "";
                            

                            foreach (var item in multiple.SelectedValue)
                            {
                                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Linha_Encomendas (Produto) VALUES(@prod1);", con);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod1", item.ToString());
                                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    
                    else
                    {
                        Erro.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Erro.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Dropdown list example:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `didnt work`? Did you debug the code and check how many times the foreach loop executes? Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824638/select-multiple-value-in-dropdownlist-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/multiselect-dropdownlist-with-checkboxes-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp-and-vb-net-using-jquery-plugin ?

Comment: i am using a ddl and not a listbox i can try using one but can i search for an item on a listbox ? because i am using the dropdown list because i can search for the items inside it